# Route Match API: Zipping and Encoding

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to use the HERE route match API, and I'm confused about the file parameter when attempting to use the GET interface. The [API](https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/route-match/topics/resource-matchroute-request.html) for the file parameter states:

> Base64 encoded string that contains the (zipped or plain) trace file
>   content. Zipped can be PKZip (used by zip, WinZip, 7Zip etc) or ZLib
>   (used by deflate) format. Only used for GET requests. In POST
>   requests, the file is sent as request body, not Base64 encoded, plain
>   or zipped. Note: Browsers limit the size of the file to a few KB when
>   passed in a GET request.

I've chosen to use the GPX format for my waypoints. Questions:

1. What is the required character encoding of the underlying XML
   characters when sending plain or zipped trace file content?
2. Are there specifications for the compression method (Deflate, Deflate64,
   etc.) and compression level?
3. Are there required specifications for
   the type of base64 encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I can definitively answer #3, and that requires URL safe encoding.